# Flatten a C# Dictionary of Lists with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary in C#:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

How can I use Linq to flatten this into one `List<string>` that contains all of the lists in the Dictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Very easily:

```
var list = dictionary.Values              // To get just the List<string>s
                     .SelectMany(x => x)  // Flatten
                     .ToList();           // Listify
```

Here the `SelectMany` call takes a sequence of inputs (the lists which make the values of the dictionary) and projects each single input into another sequence of outputs - in this case "the elements of the list". It then flattens that sequence of sequences into a single sequence.

Comment: Cool. How does SelectMany differ from Select?

Comment: @Paul I'm so tempted to just comment saying, "it selects many", but actually that's pretty much it. If you have an enumerable (or queryable) object that when enumerated returns yet more enumerable objects, such as a list of lists or an array of hash-sets, etc, it selects the elements of those objects. So in this where values is an `ICollection<List<string>>` it returns an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @Default: Yup - see http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/27/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-9-selectmany.aspx

Comment: @JonHanna Best to-the-point explanation of SelectMany I have ever seen.  Not only brief, but something I can remember.

Comment: The problem with this is that we los the keys, I imagined something like a key/value with the keys duplicated

Comment: @LuizBicalho: That's not a "problem with this" - it's a matter of "I want to do something other than what the question asks". If you're looking for something else, ask a new question...

Answer (score 12):

as a query

```
var flattened = from p in dictionary
                from s in p.Value
                select s;
```

or as methods...

```
var flattened = dictionary.SelectMany(p => p.Value);
```

I like this over what others have done as I'm passing the whole dictionary into the Linq query rather than just the values.

Answer (score 7):

[`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) is the easiest way to flatten things:

```
Dictionary.Values.SelectMany(x => x).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an instance called dict:

```
dict.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value.Select(str => str));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
dict.Values.Aggregate(new List<String>(), (a, b) => a.Concat(b));
```