# LINQ - Flatten a generic dictionary of lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, collections

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9420613/1203540) answer to somebody else's question, I am trying to make a method which will do this for a dictionary of any type.

So far I have come up with the following function, but I am getting a

> type arguments for method cannot be inferred

on the SelectMany clause.

```cs
public List<T> FlattenDictionary<T>(Dictionary<object, T> dictionary)
{
    var list = dictionary.Values              // To get just the List<string>s
             .SelectMany(x => x)  // Flatten
             .ToList();           // Listify

    return list;
}
```

Following the answer from @Ctznkane525, I have come up with the following:

```cs
public List<T> FlattenListDictionary<I, T>(Dictionary<I, T> dictionary) where T : IEnumerable<T>
{
    var list = dictionary.Values              // To get just the List<string>s
             .SelectMany(x => x)  // Flatten
             .ToList();           // Listify

    return (List <T>) list;
}
```

This now compiles without any errors but I still can't use the function because I get an error. Take the following example:

```cs
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
var list_1 = new List<string>();
list_1.Add("hello");
list_1.Add("good morning");
list_1.Add("hi");

var list_2 = new List<string>();
list_2.Add("cat");
list_2.Add("dog");
list_2.Add("mouse");

dictionary[10] = list_1;
dictionary[320] = list_2;

var list = (List<string>) FlattenListDictionary(dictionary);
```

With our without the cast I get the following error:

> The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' cannot be used as a
> type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
> 'FlattenListDictionary<I,T>(Dictionary<I,T>). There is no implicit
> reference conversion from System.Collections.Generic.List to
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collection.Generic.List>'.

I also tried changing

```cs
where T : IEnumerable<T>
```

to

```cs
where T : List<T>
```

but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample on what is your expected `T` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking you can achieve, without specifying the constraint.

```cs
public static List<T> FlattenListDictionary<I, T>(Dictionary<I, List<T>> dictionary)
{
    var list = dictionary.Values              // To get just the List<string>s
        .SelectMany(x => x)  // Flatten
        .ToList();           // Listify
        
    return list;
}
```

Calling method:

```cs
FlattenListDictionary(dictionary);
```

[Sample NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6RoMpt)

Answer (score 2):

In the other example, the value type of the dictionary is a list.  You just need a similar constraint.

where T : IEnumerable - should do that.

```
public List<T> FlattenDictionary<T>(Dictionary<object, T> dictionary) where T : IEnumerable<T>
{
    var list = dictionary.Values              // To get just the List<string>s
                 .SelectMany(x => x)  // Flatten
                 .ToList();

    return list;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It now compiles but I can't make use of it. Please see edited question.